# Query without duplicates & aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause issue. - REPEX

Tags: sql

My background is in R and I use SQL for simple bulky queries which I later refine with R, hence apologies for my pedantics.

I am running simple Azure SQL database for testing and I'm getting into the SQL optimization to ensure I'm pulling only the necessary data into R.

A sample table of what the db looks like follows:

```
-- Create a sample table:
CREATE TABLE distinct_repex
(
    invoice_num INT,
    invoice_suffix INT,
    company_name VARCHAR(32),
    invoice_amt DECIMAL
);

-- Sample Data for the Table:
INSERT INTO distinct_repex(invoice_num, invoice_suffix, company_name, invoice_amt)
VALUES
('1234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1001'),
('1234', '2', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1001'),
('1234', '3', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1001'),
('2234', '1', 'Saul Badman LLC','1002'),
('2234', '2', 'Saul Badman LLC','1002'),
('3234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1003'),
('4234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1004'),
('4234', '1', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1004'),
('4234', '2', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1004'),
('4234', '3', 'Saul Goodman LLC','1004'),
('5234', '1', 'Ax-Capital LLC','1005'),
('5234', '1', 'Ax-Capital LLC','1005'),
('5234', '2', 'Ax-Capital LLC','1005'),
('5234', '3', 'Ax-Capital LLC','1005');
```

As seen above there are repeated invoice numbers with different suffixes, some of which are duplicate (i.e: invoice 4234 has two 1 suffixes)

I'm trying to query all UNIQUE (invoice_num & invoice_suffix) pairs with the name of the company and the invoice_amt.

At first I tried:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix
FROM 
    dbo.distinct_repex
GROUP BY 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix
HAVING 
    COUNT(invoice_num) = 1
ORDER BY 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num;
```

Which got me the following:

```
1234    1
1234    2
1234    3
2234    1
2234    2
3234    1
4234    2
4234    3
5234    2
5234    3
```

I noticed that I'm not actually capturing any of the duplicated invoice_num & invoice_suffix pair for invoices 4234 suffix 1 and invoice 5234 suffix 1, both which have duplicated values, I was trying to bring back only 1 of each but I'm getting none instead.

Another issue is that I am unfamiliar with how to pull relevant information given a GROUP BY, for example (not working):

```
SELECT 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_amt
    dbo.distinct_repex.company_name
FROM 
    dbo.distinct_repex
GROUP BY 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix
HAVING 
    COUNT(invoice_num) = 1
ORDER BY 
    dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num;
```

With the above, I get an error with regards to the aggregate function.

> Column 'dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_amt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The query output I'm trying to actually get:

| invoice_num | invoice_suffix | company_name | invoice_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1001 |
| 1234 | 2 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1001 |
| 1234 | 3 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1001 |
| 2234 | 1 | Saul Badman LLC | 1002 |
| 2234 | 2 | Saul Badman LLC | 1002 |
| 3234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1003 |
| 4234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1004 |
| 4234 | 2 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1004 |
| 4234 | 3 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1004 |
| 5234 | 1 | Ax-Capital LLC | 1005 |
| 5234 | 2 | Ax-Capital LLC | 1005 |
| 5234 | 3 | Ax-Capital LLC | 1005 |

In the presented case, the 'invoice_amt' column represents the **TOTAL of the invoice**, that is why I just want to bring that information after I "delt" with the invoice number & suffix duplicates.

Since I'm here, might as well ask... What if invoice_amt column was **not the total** and I had to add these column and summarize as above desired output but now only with the totals.

For example (desired query result):

| invoice_num | invoice_suffix | company_name | invoice_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 3003 |
| 2234 | 1 | Saul Badman LLC | 2004 |
| 3234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 1003 |
| 4234 | 1 | Saul Goodman LLC | 3012 |
| 5234 | 1 | Ax-Capital LLC | 3015 |

I tried doing the following with no avail:

```
-- GENERATE THE LIST HAVING 1 COUNT:
SELECT dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
--dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix,
sum(dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_amt) AS sum_inv_amt
--dbo.distinct_repex.company_name

FROM dbo.distinct_repex

GROUP BY dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num,
        dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_suffix
        HAVING count(invoice_num) = 1
        ORDER BY dbo.distinct_repex.invoice_num;

-- * company_name was commented out of the query because it wasn't working, left company_name and invoice_suffix commented out.
```

But I got something like this:

| invoice_num | invoice_amt |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1001 |
| 1234 | 1001 |
| 1234 | 1001 |
| 2234 | 1002 |
| 2234 | 1002 |
| 3234 | 1003 |
| 4234 | 1004 |
| 4234 | 1004 |
| 5234 | 1005 |
| 5234 | 1005 |

As before, I'm still not able to bring fields like company name because of the aggregate function error, not to mention the summing up  of the invoice_amt column did not work.

Any suggestions on how to get the query output as desired?

Thank you for your time and insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to query all UNIQUE (invoice_num & invoice_suffix) pairs with the name of the company and the invoice_amt.

I interpret this as saying that you want all pairs that appear only once in the table.  If so, a simple way would be:

```
SELECT r.invoice_num, r.invoice_suffix,
       MAX(r.company_name) as company_name,
       MAX(r.invoice_amt) asinvoice_amt
FROM dbo.distinct_repex r
GROUP BY r.invoice_num, r.invoice_suffix
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY r.invoice_num;
```

If you actually want all pairs but to only appear once, then you can remove the `HAVING` clause.

If the `COUNT(*) = 1`, then `MAX()` returns the one value.  An aggregation function is needed, but either `MAX()` or `MIN()` will do.

Also not the use of table aliases.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Looks like a minor typo on COUN(*) ?

Also, isn't the line itself not necessary, since we're grouping by the duplicate rows anyways?

Otherwise this seems like a great answer.

Comment: @gordon, ty for answer. It is not clear to me how these aggregation functions work when dealing with text. What you proposed works and I can tune it to deliver what I wish, but I still don't understand the aggregation function well.... Based on your previous example, I would infer that `SELECT 
       MAX(r.company_name) as company_name

FROM dbo.distinct_repex r` 
would bring simply the list of "unique" (true sense of word) company names, but it doesn't. Do you mind explaining why what I thought is incorrect please?

Comment: @Technobrat . . . `MAX()` and `MIN()` work on almost any datatype.  You can investigate collations if you want to understand more.